How to add collision with hair when using the method of geometry nodes to make hair? (Unsure what this method is called still)
How to add collision with hair when using the method of geometry nodes to make hair?
Unsure what this method is called still
Kinda unsure if what to do from here other than repeating the steps all over again, experiment again, or try to find alternative methods that might be easier.

As far as I know, physics are not yet implemented for the new hair (geometry nodes hair)

Yikes well that makes things more complicated. Guess that means there's no real workaround either sadly. So much for this being an optional method.
